# Slow initialization of apache cxf client

Tags: java, apache, soap, cxf

I'm using wsdl2java generated classes and this code:

```
MyService f = new MyService();
MyServicePortType type = f.getMyServicePortType();
```

Each of these calls is taking up to 30 seconds. Why is that?

Answer (score 8):

After hours of googling and tinkering the problem was in how scheme files were referenced:
although WSDL and XSD were locally stored there was still some referenced to w3.org that looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSchema 200102//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd" [...

<import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
```

w3.org server was resposing super-slowly hence the slow initialization of my client.

I have changed the reference to local:

```
<import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I owe you a great debt since I have been struggling with this for days and your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Indeed w3.org URLs take ages to respond, however there is actually no reason why a SOAP client generated from a WSDL should still need to parse the WSDL at runtime.

**In fact it does not**, however default generated construstors force that.

I've discovered that it's possible to skip this by instantiating the service port in a different way and specify the service endpoint via request context as follows:

```java
// creating the service this way passes null as the wsdlLocation, preventing the runtime resolution and parsing of the wsdl
Service service =  ZefixService.create(ZefixService.SERVICE);

ZefixServicePortType zefixServicePort = service.getPort(ZefixServicePortType.class);


Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) zefixServicePort).getRequestContext();
// because we create the service without the wsdl location, we need to specify the service base url ourselves
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, Configuration.get(Constants.API_BASE_URI_PROPERTY));
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, Configuration.get(Constants.USER_PROPERTY));
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, Configuration.get(Constants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY));

return zefixServicePort;
```

I hope this turns useful for you and others in the future.

Thanks again