# Jetty start-up time improvement

Tags: web-services, spring, jetty, cxf

I am using apache CXF to generate java source classes from wsdls (aprox 50), which are loaded in jetty server. Jetty (v.7.4.5) is started programmatically using org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server->start() within another java applications.

Jetty server when these classes are not included, starts very fast (less than 3 secs.), but when the war bundle with the services is included it takes more than 40 sec in windows os. Issue is even worse in Solaris where it takes around 3 minutes.

Service implementers during loading are not initialized and they do not require any sort of resources and they should not be the reason for the delay. No additional jar files are included in the .war file, since they are  already preloaded from the application starting jetty. Nevertheless web.xml uses web-app metadata-complete="true"  flag.

We use spring configuration and related spring beans are lazily initialized.

I have already checked the following cases, but neither of them is related with the aforementioned issue.

[Slow initialization of apache cxf client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330547/slow-initialization-of-apache-cxf-client)
http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Slow-Init-Time-td563933.html

Additionally I have tried loading half of the services and load time in windows  was approximately 25 seconds while in Solaris remained around 2 minutes.

I would like to ask ways to troubleshoot, what is causing the delay in order to reduce the initialization time to a minimum. More specifically:

1) Why do you think this delay exists(especially in Solaris).
   2) How can I get JVM memory and CPU configurations for Jetty? 
      Is there a way to modify them through Jetty.xml configuration file?

Thank you in advance any ideas are highly appreciated,
Karl.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why the difference exists between the two OS. Though applying jvm parameter
-Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.fastBoot=true makes jetty start up twice as fast